# How to Create Hyperlinks using path and cell value with VBA loop

Tags: excel, loops, hyperlink, excel-formula, vba

I am having problems creating a loop to create the hyperlinks to open a folder.
The Folder Name I'm trying to open is in column A, starting on row 5.

The path is to a folder on the Desktop

I need the loop to correctly create hyperlinks to each folder corresponding to the Value in column A

I originally created a Hyperlink formula and excel auto completed the column but for some reason only the first hyperlink works while the others all say "can not open specified file".

here's the code i entered into the end of a marcro...

```
''CREATE HYPERLINKS
Range("B2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "C:\Users\tfd\Desktop\The FILES\theFILES"
Selection.Font.Bold = False
Range("B5").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=HYPERLINK(R[-3]C&""\""&[@SITE],[@FULLNAME])"
Range("A1").Select

End Sub
```

and the hyperlink I manually entered into cell B5 was...

```
=HYPERLINK(B2&"\"&[@SITE],[@FULLNAME])
```

Any and All help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How we will know, why it saying so? Seeing your code may give us a view of error to help you.

Comment: Normally `HYPERLINK` formula would work for this. Could you share a screenshot of your workbook, your `HYPERLINK` formula and also one of the formula Excel copy-created by dragging?

Comment: If you go "Formulas" > "Evaluate Formula", you can check what the output hyperlink path is (of course, if you have not specified a `[friendly_name]` then you can just read it out of the cell value) - is this a valid path to your file?

Comment: @Harun24HR i edited my question with some code and a formula

Comment: @HakanERDOGAN unfortunately i cannot screenshot, but i'm referencing a column in a table one called SITE and the other called FULLNAME and referencing a path spelled out in B2. I need column B Filled starting at the first row of the table (B5).

Comment: @Chronocidal After looking at this again with a night's rest, It appears that the path reference changes(moves down a row) for every cell auto populated. How do I ensure the formula stays on B2 for the Formula but still have Excel auto poplulate?

Comment: Use `B$2` if you want it to stay on row 2, `$B2` if you want it to stay in column B, or `$B$2` if you want it to stay in column B, row 2.  The `$` 'locks' the reference so that it doesn't move when the formula does